# Git and remote delete. How to get rid of delete messages

Tags: git, github

I did a git rm files.

Now..every time I commit...I get these list of messages.

```
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-09-30-203341.870515.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-09-30-204815.768443.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-164818.022385.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-165008.142723.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-170336.512638.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-170805.974529.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-172309.579716.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-180812.236897.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-180949.890997.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-181836.475853.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-182011.676711.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-193522.135573.html
#   deleted:    requester2/temp/snippets-2012-10-01-194152.563202.html
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

So...all works but is rather annoying.  What left do I have to do?  I committed.  This has been going on for days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
git rm `git ls-files --deleted` && git commit
```

then

`git push`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you deleted your local files, but this deletion was not committed in git (maybe you did a `git reset` along the way, or some other action).

Try to re-run

```
git rm <files>
git commit
```

and if you want to send these modifications to the remote server :

```
git push origin
```